# Give an example of function where f is discontinuous and |f| is differentiable

Tags: calculus

***Give an example of function where f is discontinuous and |f| is differentiable***

$f(x)$ = $\frac{1}{x}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} = -\infty$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} = \infty$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}$ !=$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}$

and then we get discontinuous function

and where |f| is differentiable

$\frac{-d}{dx} \frac{1}{|x|} = \frac{-d}{dx} \frac{|x|}{x^2}$ = (-x/|x|)/(x^2) = -1/x|x|

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $1/x$ is continuous, though.

Comment: I didn't understand the question at first, but I assume @Horacio's interpretation is correct. So I edited the question. If we have misunderstood, please clarify.

Comment: Please learn to format your questions with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also see [guidelines for questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational and $-1$ if $x$ is irrational. This is discontinuous everywhere, but its absolute value is just a constant, so is differentiable.

Comment: I just thought.. is there a example different from this one you gave? This is the first thing that comes to mind when seeing that question, but now I got curious. (:

Comment: @IvoTerek: there are plenty of examples along similar lines. Let $f(x)=x^2+1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-(x^2+1)$ if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: Yes, surely, I think I wasn't clear enough.. I meant something that wasn't along the lines of breaking the domain in rationals and irrationals..

Comment: @IvoTerek: if you only want a discontinuity at one point, then the example of Horacio Oliveira can be made to work: $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq 0$ and $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take, for instance $f(x) = \frac{ |x| }{x} $. $f$ is discontinuous at the origin. But $|f| = 1 $

Comment: Only if you specify the value at the origin to be $\pm1$. Otherwise it's undefined at the origin and continuous.